# Solving system of equations where variables are multiplied together

Tags: systems-of-equations

I'm trying to figure out a way to solve a system of equations where variables are multiplied together. Fairly similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122933/how-to-solve-a-system-of-equations-with-variables-multiplied-to-each-other), however the example used seems simpler than what I want to do.

As an example, let's say I have 3 variables and 3 equations. All my equations are in the form:

$$c_1x + c_2y + c_3z + c_4xy + c_5xz + c_6yz + c_7xyz = 0$$

Constants can be either $0$ or a positive whole number. Variables are either $0$ or $1$.

I've been trying to figure out if/how to use substitution and/or elimination. I've also seen some solutions that replace the multiplied variables with a single new variable. I'm not entirely sure whether that would help or how to properly do it.

How should I go about solving this system?

Edit 1:
I looked back at the problem I'm trying to solve and the constants can be negative.

Comment: If your variables can only be zero or one you onla have èight possible solutions. It is trivial to check them through.

Comment: You can solve such systems of equations over, say, real or complex numbers by using resultants or Groebner bases. In your case it is over $\Bbb F_2$, which is trivial as Kurt said. But may be you want to consider real numbers instead. Can you write down the three equations in $x,y,z$? Also, are your constants fixed? If not, they are further variables.

Comment: Potentially there are a lot more variables. Enough that I don't think checking all combinations is going to work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde when you say write down the equations in x,y,z are you wanting the actual equations? I don't know the actual equations. I guess the best explanation is that a system of equations can be given to me and I need to solve it. Essentially I want to write a computer program to do this. Constants are fixed.

Comment: I think it's going to be over 30 variables. I assumed that would be too slow for my needs, but I probably should test it just to see. Maybe it won't be. I'll Google for those and see if they can help. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you could first consider new variables $x,y,z$, and $z_1=xy$, $z_2=xz$, $z_3=yz$ and $z_4=xyz$, then your system consists of linear equations. Solve this first, then the rest is much easier.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, that's actually the path I was thinking about trying, but I haven't found a good explanation on what to do after I introduce new variables. With introducing the new variables, the original equations become linear, but now I have more variables than equations correct?

Comment: Why do you have more variables than equations? I count less than $10$ variables, and you have $100000$ equations? It is the other way around, probably. You see, therefore it would be good if you give a meaningful explicit example, which you want to know (and why). You cannot solve arbitrary such systems. It really depends on your choices.

Comment: I think where I'm getting confused is where/how the equations created for the new variables come in. So, in the original example, I start with 3 variables and 3 equations. After creating variables, I now have 3 linear equations in 7 variables. And then I have 4 new equations which are in 7 variables. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: I guess the question I really have is whether the 4 new equations are now part of my system of equations? I tried an example problem a few days ago like this and it didn't really figure out like I thought it would.

Comment: @Dan "*Constants can be either $0$ or a positive whole number. Variables are either $0$ or $1$*" $\;$ A sum of non-negative terms can only be zero iff each term is zero. If $\,c_1 \ne 0\,$ then $\,x=0\,$, and similar for $\,c_2, c_3\,$. Otherwise if  $\,c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0\,$ and $\,c_4 \ne 0\,$ then $\,xy=0\,$ so the problem breaks down into solving two systems for $\,x = 0\,$and $\,y=0\,$ respectively, and similarly for $\,c_5, c_6\,$. Otherwise $\cdots$

Comment: I may have been mistaken about he constants being only positive. I believe they can be negative.